# Creating a data frame out of a list of data frames

Tags: r

I need to do a multi-million count on How many people have X job by Gender, by UF, by many years.
So, let's say, test.frame1 is y1, test.frame2 is y2, and so on.
I need to count in each UF, for each data frame, how many women and man have J1, 2, and 3. Then, I need to  make a table showing the progression of the count. A table that`d look like this> [image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(forcats)
#Creating Reproducible Data#

set.seed(4)
UF <- c("North", "South", "West", "East","North", "South", "West", "East","North", "South", "West", "East")
Gender <- c("Woman", "Woman", "Woman", "Woman","Man", "Man", "Man", "Man","Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman")
Job <- c("J1","J1", "J2", "J2", "J3", "J3","J1","J1", "J2", "J2", "J3", "J3")
Wage1 <- lapply(1,function(x){sample(1:150,12,replace = T)})
Wage2 <- lapply(1,function(x){sample(1:150,12,replace = T)})
Wage3 <- lapply(1,function(x){sample(1:150,12,replace = T)})
test.frame1 <- data.frame(UF, Gender, Wage1, Job)
test.frame2 <- data.frame(UF, Gender, Wage2, Job)
test.frame3 <- data.frame(UF, Gender, Wage3, Job)
names(test.frame1)[3] <- 'Wage'
names(test.frame2)[3] <- 'Wage'
names(test.frame3)[3] <- 'Wage'

data_list <- list(test.frame1, test.frame2, test.frame3)

Count <-  lapply(data_list, function(x){
  test <- plyr::dlply(x, "UF", function(x) as.data.frame(table(x$Gender,x$Job)))
})

DFEtnia <- as.data.frame(sapply(Count,function(x){
  do.call(rbind,lapply(x,frequency))[,-1]
}))
```

The DFEtnia should be a data frame with all counts of jobs.

I`d also like to remove any job that has 0 columns.

Comment: Is what we see in the example output for a single `UF`?  If so, how do you want the result to look that contains all `UF` values?

Comment: Ops, forgot about that. A table per UF is what I want as the end result, but I guess the DFEtnia would have UF as a variable/column. So like, that table over there is a byproduct of DFEtnia, and in DFEtnia you have Woman - J1 - North ...

Comment: There is no Year column in your example is that relevant?

Comment: The year is each test.frame. So the result from test.frame 1 is year 1.